# multiple div in .html()?

Tags: jquery

```
var div1 = $("<div>");
var div2 = $("<div>");
var div3 = $("<div>");

$('#container').html('').append(div1).append(div2).append(div3);
```

What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with doing it this way?

Comment: I was hoping something like this: $('#container').html(div1+div2+div3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you are doing, but if you don't need references to the elements you could just as well do:

```
$("#container").html("<div></div><div></div><div></div>");
```

**Edit**

You could do something like below to make the statement more terse without any real benefit.

```
$("#container").append(div1.add([div2, div3]));
```

Comment: I was hoping there is a way like $('#container').html(div1+div2+div3)

Comment: does your edit also clear out the contents before appending?  (e.g. `html('')`)

Comment: +1 - I like the div1.add[div2,div3] syntax...didn't think of that.

Comment: @D Hoerster not as written, it would require an `empty()` or the like in there to clear out the current contents.

Answer (score 1):

I can see no problem with your method. However, you may re-arrange your code a bit, for the sake of readability -

```
var div1 = $(<div>);
var div2 = $(<div>);
var div3 = $(<div>);

$('#container').html('')
               .append(div1)
               .append(div2)
               .append(div3);
```

Other than than, your method is fine.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Is it better to use `empty` instead of `html('')`?

`$("#container").empty().append(div1).append(div2).append(div3);`

Just seems more descriptive about what's being done.  I'm not sure if `html('')` is more performant -- if so, then use that.

Answer (score 0):

> I was hoping there is a way like
>   $('#container').html(div1+div2+div3)

**There is!**

```
var div1 = "<div></div>";
var div2 = "<div></div>";
var div3 = "<div></div>";

$("#container").html(div1 + div2 + div3);
```

The variables are just strings,  **not** jQuery objects so you can do that easily.

I'm not 100% what you're trying to achieve, I think if you post your requirement people will have better solutions.

Cheers,

Marko